# Controlling Spacing after paragraph

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm sure this is trivial, but I'm new to LaTeX and having trouble getting some formatting correct. I want two columns with bold headings and non bold text after. One of the headings, "experiments" has too much info to fit on one line so I want the spacing to be tighter. I've tried several different options but I can't get it right. Here's my attempt at a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.1in,right=1.1in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
%% Heading Section%%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\doublespacing
\raggedright
\textbf{Name:} Jayson \\
\textbf{Course Number:} ECGR 2155\\
\textbf{Experiment Titles:}\\
\singlespacing
    Network Analysis,
    Th\'{e}venin and Norton Circuits,
    Time Constant of an RC Network  
\doublespacing  
\textbf{Lab Partner:} Marcus \\
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\doublespacing
\textbf{Date:} \today\\
\textbf{Section:} L03 \\
\textbf{Experiment Numbers:} 8,9,10\\
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing a blank line before `\doublespacing\textbf{Lab Partner:} Marcus`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a blank line before

```
\doublespacing
\textbf{Lab Partner:} Marcus
```

The paragraph has not yet ended, so `\doublespacing` takes over.

However, I'd do it differently from switching between double and single spacing: set (locally) a non zero `\parskip`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.1in,right=1.1in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
%% Heading Section%%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\raggedright
\textbf{Name:} Jayson

\textbf{Course Number:} ECGR 2155

\textbf{Experiment Titles:}\\
Network Analysis,
Th\'{e}venin and Norton Circuits,
Time Constant of an RC Network

\textbf{Lab Partner:} Marcus
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\textbf{Date:} \today

\textbf{Section:} L03

\textbf{Experiment Numbers:} 8,9,10
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If your data are always laid out as shown, perhaps a template form is better:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.1in,right=1.1in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\headingsection}{m}
 {
  \keys_set:nn { labnotes/heading } { #1 }
  \par\noindent
  \begin{tabular}{
    @{}
    >{\raggedright}p{\dim_eval:n{.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dim_eval:n{.5\textwidth-\tabcolsep}}
    @{}
  }
  \textbf{Name:}~\l_labnotes_heading_name_tl &
  \textbf{Date:}~\l_labnotes_heading_date_tl \\[\baselineskip]
  \textbf{Course~Number:}~\l_labnotes_heading_coursenumber_tl &
  \textbf{Section:}~\l_labnotes_heading_section_tl \\[\baselineskip]
  \textbf{Experiment~Titles:}~\newline\l_labnotes_heading_exptitles_tl
    % add here the spacing
    \vspace{\baselineskip} &
  \textbf{Experiment~Numbers:}~\l_labnotes_heading_expnumbers_tl\vspace{\baselineskip} \\
  \textbf{Lab~Partners:}~\l_labnotes_heading_partners_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \par
 }

\keys_define:nn { labnotes/heading }
 {
  name .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_name_tl,
  date .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_date_tl,
  coursenumber .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_coursenumber_tl,
  section .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_section_tl,
  exptitles .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_exptitles_tl,
  expnumbers .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_expnumbers_tl,
  partners .tl_set:N = \l_labnotes_heading_partners_tl,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\headingsection{
  name=Jayson,
  date=\today,
  coursenumber=ECGR 2155,
  section=L03,
  exptitles={
    Network Analysis,
    Th\'{e}venin and Norton Circuits,
    Time Constant of an RC Network
  },
  expnumbers={8, 9, 10},
  partners=Marcus,
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly how I would like it to look. I also discovered that \begin{singlespace}..\end{singlespace} gave good results, but I like your solution better.

Comment: Needed to say, `\baselineskip` is really a _lot_. One might prefer something smaller, like `2ex`.

Comment: @tohecz It depends; this seems a lab notes heading, so it might be a good choice.

Comment: @JayCle I have added an alternative version that might ease typing those headers.

Comment: They are always laid out the same and I will be writing about 20 more of these before the end of my schooling so that will be helpful. Now I just have to look up what half of those commands are!

Comment: @JayCle It's just setting up a key-value system and using the set keys for filling a `tabular`.

Comment: @egreg I really like how you implement the key-val expressions in this example.

Comment: @egreg As a programmer, I am made curious by your second example, still. I keep trying to find some documentation on it, but they all use a package of some sort and you seem to have just used the default latex syntax. Could you point me to a document or site which explains how to use key-val expressions?

Comment: @JayCle That's the key-value interface provided by `expl3`, the programmer's interface of LaTeX3. If you do `texdoc interface3` you'll find the documentation.